# Using a function to determine weather a list and a tuple both with variables match

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, tuples

i have a tuple within a tuple:

```
 meals = (
\# name of dish \[0\], ingredients \[1\]
 ("fish_sticks", ("frozen fish", "potatoes", "mustard")),
("chicken_curry", ("chicken", "curry paste", "carrots", "potatoes", "rice")),
("chicken_veg", ("chicken", "potatoes", "carrots")),
("pasta", ("spaghetti", "tomato sauce"))
```

I have to return a `true/false` depending on if what I have in my fridge = the meal, to see if I can make it.

This is where I started:

```
def meal_list(meal, ingridients_list):
    for item in meal: 
        if meal == ingridients_list:
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
    return meal_list("fishsticks",("frozen fish", "potatoes", "mustard") )
```

I do realize that I have no list to show the code what is right and wrong. just dong know how to get going.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if ALL ingredients needed to make the meal are in your `ingridients_list`. Currently, you print immediately after the first iteration of the loop (which isn't structured correctly).

Try:

```
def meal_list(meal, ingridients_list):
    #get all the ingredients for the meal
    needed = [i for m, i in meals if m==meal][0]

    #check if items needed are in your ingredients
    for item in needed:
        if item not in ingridients_list:
            return False
    return True

>>> meal_list("fish_sticks",("frozen fish", "potatoes", "mustard"))
True
```